# how can i get all documents created today at 8am in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hi everyone i'm working with meteor js and i'm trying to get all documents from a mongoDB collection created at a specific hour of the day for example today at 8am how can i do this?
i'll be thankfull for any help

Comment: It's a Mongo question, you should not mention Meteor to make it more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your documents, you must set the creation date:

```
MyCollection.insert({ text: "abc", createdAt: new Date() });
```

then, you can filter your data:

1. If you want the documents created in an interval:

   ```
   MyCollection.find(
      {createdAt: {
         $gte: new Date("Sat Jul 30 2016 8:00:00"),
         $lt: new Date("Sat Jul 30 2016 9:00:00"),
      }},
   {sort: {createdAt:1}});
   ```
2. Or documents created exactly at 8am:

   ```
   MyCollection.find({createdAt: new Date("Sat Jul 30 2016 8:00:00")});
   ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using collection 2 package, you have to add this to your collection

```
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
      } else {
        this.unset(); 
    }
  }
```

After that you have to add the createdAt field to your query.